# Redirect my document folder to Onedrive

Tags: powershell

I am needing to have a PS script to re-direct a user's my documents to their Onedrive.
I currently have a batch file that will create a directory in OneDrive but I need it to actually redirect the location so there is not 2 my documents. And would prefer using PS.
Here is my attempted PS Script..

```
$answer = Show-MsgBox -title "Changing the User Library Paths" -prompt "Do you want to change the user documents folder?" -BoxType YesNo -Icon Question
if [$answer -eq "Yes"]
    {
    $MyDirs = Get-ChildItem "$HOME" -Name -Exclude "Links", "Searches"
    if [$MyDirs]
        { 
        $ShellFolder = "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders"
        $UserShellFolder = "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders"
        foreach [$MyDir in $MyDirs]
            {
            $RegName = Get-RegistryKeyPropertiesAndValues $ShellFolder |Where-Object {$_.Value -match "$MyDir"} |foreach {$_.property}
            $answer = Show-MsgBox -title "Change $MyDir Folder" -prompt "Do you want to change the $Mydir folder?" -BoxType YesNo -Icon Question
            if [$answer -eq "Yes"] 
                {
                $inputbox = $null
                $inputbox = Show-Inputbox -message "Enter the path of the $MyDir folder" -title "Entering path..." -default "D:\Users\$env:username\$MyDir"
                if [$inputbox] 
                    {
                    if [![Test-Path "D:\Users\$env:username\$MyDir"]] {New-Item "D:\Users\$env:username\$MyDir" -ItemType Directory -Force}
                    Set-ItemProperty -Path $ShellFolder -Name $RegName -Value $inputbox
                    Set-ItemProperty -Path $UserShellFolder -Name $RegName -Value $inputbox
                    Move-Item "$HOME\$MyDir\*" "D:\Users\$env:username\$MyDir" -Force
                    attrib +r "D:\Users\$env:username\$MyDir"
                    rd $HOME\$MyDir -recurse -Force
                    }
                }
            }
        Show-MsgBox -title "Press OK to continue" -prompt "Folder redirection done!" -BoxType OkOnly -Icon Exclamation
        cls
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to change documents location
and Edit for multiple folders

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms    
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic

$answer =[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Changing the User Library Paths","Do you want to change the user documents folder?" ,"YesNo","Question")
if ($answer -eq "Yes")
    {
    #read your registery location documents C:\user\someone\documents
    $RegPersonal = Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" -name "Personal" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    $RegPersonal.personal = $RegPersonal.personal.trim().ToLower()

    #ansver your Documents Current Location 
    $answer =[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Current Location is  "+$RegPersonal.personal ,"Do you want to change the user documents folder?" ,"YesNo","Question")
     }

   #input new directory
    if ($answer -eq "Yes") 

        {
            $inputbox = $null  
            $inputbox = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Enter the new path " +$RegPersonal.personal+ "folder", "Entering path...  C:\Users\"+$env:username+"\"+$RegPersonal) 
         }
             if ($answer -eq "No"){
             [void][System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Canceled by the user")     
             exit
             }

        #change new directory location register
        if ($inputbox) 
            {
             Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders' -name Personal "$inputbox"

        }               

    [void][System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Press OK to continue You need restart your Pc","Folder redirection done!",[Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::"OK",[Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::"Exclamation")
```

Comment: Is there anyway to add %UserProfile% to autoroute?

Comment: Or use this but add favorites and pictures additionally?

Comment: You can add a folders favorites pictures in the script ,one by one

Comment: or 1 question to user change al folders to onedrive.  I have changed our users doc,pic,favo  to c:\users\someone\onedrive-business\  Can you add your comment What location do you want to work?                          %UserProfile%\onedive-folder